# ActiveRecords Associations: Users, Reports, and Groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model, associations

Newbie to ActiveRecords associations, and can't quite grasp it yet. The app I am building should enable users to create reports and also join/create organizations that contain shared reports generated by members.

This is what I came up with, but after reading up on the subject this doesn't seem nearly correct.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :organizations
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    #has_many :users
end
```

How would I go about building these associations? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :organizations
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :reports, through: :users
end
```

The key here is `has_many :reports, through: :users`. When you do `Organization.find(1).reports` this tells Rails to get the reports by joining the users relation.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Thanks for the clarification max!